# why my code is so slow?

Tags: android, performance

i runing this code on android after load a cursor with the query i pass to the adapter, but my date is in long in milliseconds format so i need to format properly before load the adapter!
problem is this code is taking 14 seconds to pass a 50 items load, the problem get worst if i call it inside the adapter getView cause get slow when i scrool, if i take this function out the program runs smoothly

this is call inside my listfragment

```
private String dateFormatPatternEdited(long timeMS) {
    android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
    final Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar sDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    sDate.setTimeInMillis(timeMS);
    long daysBetween = 0;
    while (sDate.before(eDate)) {
        sDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;
    }
    String mDateFormatPattern = FuelTrackerApplication.dateFormat.format(timeMS);
    if (daysBetween < 2){
        mDateFormatPattern = FuelTrackerApplication.timeFormat.format(timeMS);
    } else if(daysBetween < 365){
        mDateFormatPattern = df.format(FuelTrackerApplication.dateFormatPattern,timeMS).toString();
    }
    return mDateFormatPattern;
}
```

and this is were i initialize the date formats i gonna use its called inside onCreate in FuelTrackerApplication i dont think theres nothing wrong with this

```
public void initializeDateFormat() {
    android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
    dateFormatPattern = "MMM dd";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18){
        dateFormatPattern = df.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), dateFormatPattern);
    }
    dateFormat = df.getMediumDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    timeFormat = df.getTimeFormat(getApplicationContext());
    dateFormat2 = df.getLongDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on an Android emulator?

Comment: nope on my brand new galaxy s4 quad core

Comment: Could you possibly just minus the milliseconds from each other? and then instead of daysBetween, have milliseconds passed. This might be faster then looping over 365 days. You might have to be careful though with a year's milliseconds. Also are your items ordered by date?

Comment: You could also just initialise some of these variables once, like eDate.

Comment: Also forgot, what's the largest date difference you have?

Comment: this is for track when you refuel your car, but i want that same effect gmail has when you list your emails showing the dates acordly todays date

Comment: largest date difference would be the lifetime of the app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just a few things. Depending on how long ago your dates are going back. You are only interested if the days between go more then 365. So if your dates are going back for years, you're doing extra work.

```
while (sDate.before(eDate) && daysBetween <= 365) {
    sDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    daysBetween++;
}
```

Will let it break, it means if you have 20 entries going back 5 years, you don't do so much work.

It might be worth while to possibly just check the milliseconds difference. I'm not sure if this is precise enough, but it should work. It means you don't need to loop everything E.g

```
long millisecondsToday = getMilliseconds;
long timeMs = // you already have this

long millisecondsDifference = millisecondsToday - timeMs;
if (millisecondsDifference < MILLISECONDS_TWO_DAYS) // set a final variable out of this method
// etc
```

If might also be worth while initialising some of your variables once outside of the method. Like your `df`, that is being created 50 times, and then just having something set on it. Same with your `eDate`.

Comment: you where totaly right, just for initializing outside, dont even mess with the loops!

Comment: No problem, never really played with date formats but I think they are expensive to create, calendars might be as well. To avoid the year problem, you might want to add the `daysBetween <= 365` part. This just makes sure if the date is 5 years, you don't have to keep going through more years then you need

Comment: you also right i was using too large difference i wasnt thinking about that!

Answer (score 0):

i got this incredible faster and practicaly remove the hole function
instead goes like this

```
     lDateBetween = NOW - timeMS;
    if (lDateBetween < DAY)
        return FuelTrackerApplication.timeFormat.format(timeMS);
    else if (lDateBetween < YEAR)
        return df.format(FuelTrackerApplication.dateFormatPattern,timeMS).toString();
    else return FuelTrackerApplication.dateFormat.format(timeMS);
```

all calculation is made using milliseconds i also put 2 final NOW and YEAR, also df and lDateBetween
i think is the fastest i can get!